# Cannot Open local PDF in WebView showing white screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

webview showing white screen when loading local pdf 
[image]

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.documentView);
        webView.invalidate();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadData(path.toString(),"application/pdf", "UTF-8"
```

);

please help me.

Comment: can you post your path here ?

Comment: /storage/extSdCard/ULGURU/Chemistry/Chapter1-Some Basic Concepts of Chemistry/8323-2016-Admn.pdf

Comment: have you tried encoding path ?

Comment: no.am tring to convert string path to Uri path but its not working can u please give me the solution

Comment: check and if it doesn't work then let me know

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String localPath = path.toString();
 localPath  = localPath.replace(" ", "%20").trim();
```

and use it like this

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.documentView);
        webView.invalidate();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadData("file:///"+localPath,"application/pdf", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: showing W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.